# Find the fundamental group without Seifert–van Kampen theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $ R = \mathbb{R} \times \{0 \} $ be the real line, $ S = \{x \in \mathbb{C}| d(x,i) = 1 \} $, and let $ X = R \cup S $. Is there a simple method to find the fundamental group of $ X $ with only basic Algebraic Topology tools (up to chapter 9 in Munkers's Topology)?

Comment: $X$ deformation retracts onto $S$, so you just need to know the fundamental group of the circle.

Comment: That's makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deformation retract the real line component of this space onto the space $S$. From there, it shouldn't be hard to see that its fundamental group is that of the circle.

The desired deformation retraction is
$$
H(x,t) = \begin{cases}
x, & \text{if $x\in S$}\\
(1-t)x, & \text{if $x\in R$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Since $X$ is the union of $S$ and $R$, both of which are closed subspaces of $X$, the homotopy $H$ is continuous by the pasting lemma.